# making a thumbnail toolbar (windowsAPICodePack,windows 7) button invisible in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, api, windows-7, thumbnail-toolbar

I'm trying to make a thumbnail toolbar button (TTB from now on)visible when the it is clicked. I know how to do stuff when it is clicked, AddHandler etc. But if I tell it TTB.visible=false then it doesn't become invisible. If I put TTB.enabled = False it will be disabled, so it's only the visible that isn't working.

Also I put a button on my form (not a TTB) and when that is click wrote, TTB.visible = false and that didn't work, so there is no way to make it invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set TTB.visible=true after you Add it into toolbar button list.